# How do I stop IIS from sending minutely GET requests to my proxied mongrel server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, ruby-on-rails, mongrel, mongrel-rails

I have a rails application running on Windows Server 2008 running IIS7.5. I am using Application Request Routing to send requests to the Mongrel server via IIS (I didn't want to set it up like this but this was the environment I have been forced to use).

IIS seems to send a GET request to the Mongrel server once every minute. This is not a huge deal but it does cause a lot of pollution in my logs and also creates a large amount of unwanted session data.

I would really like to stop it from doing this. Is there a way?

Comment: Are you 100% certain that the requests are originating from ARR itself?  Is it possible that another application is sending the requests to ARR which is then forwarding to Mongrel?  Can you post log entries from the ARR tier as well as the Mongrel tier?

Answer (score 1):

Under the Server Farm config, can you check to see if a "URL test" is enabled under the "Health Test" option?  That's the only think I can think of in ARR that would cause un-proxied requests:

[image: Health Test Tab in IIS]

Comment: On Easter break now (yeah I know, I'm taking a few extra days...). Don't have/want remote access so it'll be 11 days until I can check this. Thanks though.

Comment: Finally got back! No, that's not it. There is absolutely nothing at all under server farms in my setup. Thanks again though.

Comment: Sorry!  Keep us posted on what you find, though!